# syntax error: inserting LPAREN

Tags: sml

This is my first time with sml.

I don't understand what is wrong with this syntax:

```
 fun merge (l1 : int list , l2 : int list) : int list = 
  if ([] , l2) then l2
  else if (l1 , []) then l1
    else (x :: xs , y :: ys) 
        if x < y then x :: (merge (xs , l2))
           else y :: (merge (l1 , ys)));
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `if` / `then` / `else` syntax is not used for pattern-matching. (You've melded two unrelated syntaxes.)

So, for example, `if ([] , l2)` does not work, because the condition in an `if` expression needs to have type `bool`, which `([], l2)` does not.

Instead, you want to write:

```
fun merge ([], l2) = l2
  | merge (l1, []) = l1
  | merge (l1 as x :: xs, l2 as y :: ys) =
       if x < y
       then x :: merge (xs, l2)
       else y :: merge (l1, ys)
```

Comment: @ShayChercavsky If a post answered your question, consider [marking it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).